# Angular Leaflet maps vs Angular google map

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 7. I have to integrate the map for my project.

In my map, i have to place multiple markers and zooming the marker, it have to display one or more markers.
And also, Update details, based on zoom to the different location.

So, which map having the options and which one is best for integrate with angular7.
Could any one please help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In terms of features ,I have to say you could pick either of them depending on your condition :

If you are using map for a big project or company i suggest using leaflet cause it is free.
My company was on google till recent changes to google maps prices then we switched to leaflet and it works great , i have used marker clustering, heat-maps,etc and it is working fine in my case .

Comment: Can you please send the link for leaflet with angular7 or angular 6 which you are used in your project

Comment: i used leaflet from leaflet website , nothing more than that . you can get map tiles from various websites btw .